# Get info about current user in Opencart

Tags: opencart

I have been work on a module with Opencart and I was wondering how I can get current user information.

I was thinking something like this: `$this->getuserid();`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I just found it out:

```
$this->customer->getFirstName();
$this->customer->getLastName();
$this->customer->getEmail();
$this->customer->getTelephone();
$this->customer->getFax();
```

and so on.

The source code (including the other methods available) is located in the [`system/library/customer.php`](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/system/library/customer.php) file.

You can use the methods just anywhere.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

There is difference between customer and user. To get current user ID (admin, manager etc) do the following:

```
$this->session->data['user_id'];
```

Comment: Exactly! I was searching for user and the answers have been for customer in so many posts, it's confusing. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get the id of the user that is currently logged in

```
$this->user->getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

In oc3

You can get the library folder in

```
your_project/system/library/cart/customer.php
```

In the customer.php file, you will get all the functions where you can call in your controller and check it out.

```
$this->customer->getId();
```

Get your customer id and etc etc you can get it from the customer.php file.

Thanks.